# Young man, protected by genetically engineered ravens; attends school that makes a population-decimating virus

Tags: story-identification, genetic-engineering

I'm searching for a book about a young man that goes to a school/academy/training institute where they get tasks and, depending how they perform, they can upgrade physical features like strength, speed, and so on. This academy is controlled by a company which also released a virus for which it also sells the medicine. Also genetically engineered ravens protect this young man.

The plot is like this: World population is decimated because of a virus. A young man is taken(am not sure if it was voluntary) by an organization or company which has a medicine for the virus. This company has also the technology, which was invented by the father of the boy, to genetically engineer people. This company send him to an institute to train/learn where depending on how you perform you can earn upgrades.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to [SFF.SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help)! Could you add some more details? e.g. approximate years (published, read), character names, etc...

Comment: The Shadow Ravens series (begins with *Cipher*) looked promising at first, but there really isn't a "school" involved in it.